# dividend files from quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

This will download dividend data for multiple stocks, each in a separate variable. The R data file names are the name of the stock followed by ".div". I.e., for Microsoft, the file would be "MSFT.div".

```
require(quantmod)
DJ30_symbols.ls <- c("MSFT", "IBM")
nDiv <- length(DJ30_symbols.ls)
for (i in 1:nDiv) {
  cat("Downloading ", i, " out of ", nDiv, "\n")
  getDividends(DJ30_symbols.ls[i], from = "1970-01-01", to = Sys.Date())
}
```

When i try to save the individual files as a csv file in my working directory, as follows:

```
write.zoo(paste(DJ30_symbols.ls[i], ".div", sep=' '),
  file = paste(DJ30_symbols.ls[i], ".csv", sep=''), index.name = "date")
```

I save files, but the data saved is not the dividends downloaded from Yahoo, but the symbol name (e.g. "MSFT.div"). I get the downloaded dividend information in a csv file if I do:

```
write.zoo(MSFT.div, file = "MSFT_div.csv", index.name = "date")
```

Is there any way I can use the variable names to read the data and save the files?

Answer (score 0):

The code `paste(DJ30_symbols.ls[i], ".div", sep=' ')` is a character string, not an object that contains the dividend data. You could use `get` to retrieve the object with that name, but it would be easier if you just had `getDividends` return the object rather than `auto.assign` it.

```
require(quantmod)
DJ30_symbols.ls <- c("MSFT", "IBM")
for (i in seq_along(DJ30_symbols.ls)) {
  cat("Downloading ", i, " out of ", nDiv, "\n")
  obj <- getDividends(DJ30_symbols.ls[i], from="1970-01-01", auto.assign=FALSE)
  write.zoo(obj, paste0(DJ30_symbols.ls[i], ".csv"), index.name="date")
}
```